# The following code compiles without error. How can I change that?

Tags: errors, conditionals, package-writing, documentclass-writing

Unlike most questions on this site, my problem is that my code compiles without error and I do not want it to.

I want to be able the check whether `\command` is defined and to do something if it is defined, but nothing if it is not. I do not want `\command` to be set to `\relax` if it is not defined. I don't want the code to have any effect at all if it is not defined.

Here's an example. In this case, it is easy to work around the issue, so this is for illustrative purposes only. That is, this particular case is not itself a problem - it is just a simple example to demonstrate the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{}{\renewcommand\chapter[1]{turtles}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

As I mentioned, in this particular case, an easy workaround is available: I can check if `\@chapter` is defined rather, using its definition as a proxy for `\chapter`.

But is there a way to check if `\chapter` is defined, without either setting it to `\relax` if it is not or checking only indirectly using a proxy?

## EDIT

This is [the third case mentioned in discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268465/the-following-code-compiles-without-error-how-can-i-change-that/268467?noredirect=1#comment644336_268467) where `\ifdefined...\fi` causes problems but the `\ifdef{}{}{}` method works well as a replacement for the `\@ifundefined{}{}{}` original. Provided by [request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268465/the-following-code-compiles-without-error-how-can-i-change-that/268467?noredirect=1#comment644339_268467).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% \usepackage{etoolbox}% for \ifdef method
% \ifdef{\chapter}{% Werner's comment on Alan Munn's answer - this method works well
\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{% original - works but \chapter no longer gives an error as it is set to \relax
% \ifdefined\chapter%ref.: Alan Munn's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268467/ - unfortunately does not work here (at least, not with the knowledge I have to implement it)
  \renewcommand\chapter{%
          \if@openright
                  \cleardoublepage
          \else
                  \clearpage
          \fi
          \thispagestyle{plain}%
          \global\@topnum\z@
          \@afterindentfalse
          \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}%  end \renewcommand\chapter
  \def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
          \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                  \if@mainmatter
                          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                          {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                  \else
                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                  \fi
          \else
                  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
          \fi
          \chaptermark{#1}%
          \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
          \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
          \if@twocolumn
                  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
          \else
                  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                  \@afterheading
          \fi}% end definition of \@chapter
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
          \vspace*{50\p@}%
          {%
                  \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
                  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                          \if@mainmatter
                                  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{14}\mdseries\centering\scshape{\@chapapp\space \thechapter}%
                                  \par\nobreak
                                  \vskip 20\p@
                          \fi
                  \fi
                  \interlinepenalty\@M
                  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bldsc\centering #1\par\nobreak
                  \vskip 40\p@
          }%
  }%    end definition \@makechapterhead
  \def\@schapter#1{%
          \if@twocolumn
                  \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
          \else
                  \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                  \@afterheading
          \fi}% end definition \@schapter
  \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
          \vspace*{50\p@}%
          {%
                  \parindent \z@ \raggedright
                  \normalfont
                  \interlinepenalty\@M
                  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bldsc\centering #1\par\nobreak
                  \vskip 40\p@
          }%
  }%    end definition \@makeschapterhead
}%      end of stuff to do only if \chapter is defined - \@ifundefined method
% }{}% \ifdef method
% \fi% \ifdefined method
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \chapter{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's one of the more interesting subject lines I've seen on TeX.sX `:P`

Comment: what is the problem of `\ifx\chapter\mtOrcfrundef\else\renewcommand\chapter[1]{turtles}\fi`?

Comment: @touhami It doesn't work in the actual code e.g. the 'third case' given above. I agree it will work for the (obviously too) minimal example I originally posted.

Comment: @cfr excuse me, I think the problem is `\@ifundefined`'s definition, one can define new command `\def\ifmtundefined#1{%
  \ifx#1\mtundef
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}`

Comment: @touhami Similar to egreg's answer? I don't understand this well enough to know, so this is just a question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest is to use the e-TeX `\ifdefined` macro instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\chapter\renewcommand\chapter[1]{turtles}\fi
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This won't work if you have other conditionals inside it (thus the source of your larger problem) in which case Werner's solution using `etoolbox` is preferred:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
  \ifdef{\chapter}{
    \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
     \else
        \clearpage
      \fi
    turtles}
}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) also provides a host of other stuff, including `\ifcsdef` or `\ifdef`. Then there's also `\ifcsname`.

Comment: Presumably `\ifdefined... \else...\fi` also works? Thanks. (I know I said I wanted it to do nothing in the question, but sometimes I do want it to do something - just not defining the command!)

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's a regular `\if...` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks stuff in my real document. It works in 2 out of 3 places, but `\chapter` still ends up getting defined by the third :(.

Comment: @cfr: What about a more comprehensive example?

Comment: @Werner Actually, your suggestion works fine. Can you write an answer? I guess it makes more sense for me to accept that. (Apologies to Alan since this answer does work with my MWE. I didn't realise that a solution might require a more complex case.)

Comment: @cfr Can you add an example to your question that shows the subsequent problem ?

Comment: @AlanMunn OK. But it is messy and maximal, I'm afraid. I wouldn't have posted this if you hadn't explicitly asked!

Comment: @AlanMunn: You should just add the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) additions to your answer.

Comment: Maybe `\ifundef` is better in light of egreg's answer?

Answer (score 6):

You lose expandability, of course, but this is the “easy” way:

```
\documentclass
%{book}
{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\endgroup}{\endgroup\renewcommand\chapter[1]{turtles}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{a}
\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The method with `\ifdef` from `etoolbox` may give wrong results if a command has already been appeared in the scope of `\@ifundefined` and so it has been made equivalent to `\relax`.

An expandable test should branch with `\ifdefined` and, in this case, seeing if the command is equivalent to `\relax`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\x@ifundefined}[3]{%
   \ifcsname #1\endcsname
     %either defined or \relax
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     %undefined
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\x@ifrelax{#1}{#2}{#3}}{#2}%
 }
\newcommand{\x@ifrelax}[3]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatletter
```

A test will show we're OK:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\foo{\x@ifundefined{bbcccddd}{undef}{def}}\show\foo
\edef\foo{\x@ifundefined{relax}{undef}{def}}\show\foo
\edef\foo{\x@ifundefined{mbox}{undef}{def}}\show\foo
\show\bbcccddd
\makeatother
```

will output

```
> \foo=macro:
->undef.
l.26 ...fundefined{bbcccddd}{undef}{def}}\show\foo

? 
> \foo=macro:
->undef.
l.27 ...x@ifundefined{relax}{undef}{def}}\show\foo

? 
> \foo=macro:
->def.
l.28 ...\x@ifundefined{mbox}{undef}{def}}\show\foo

? 
> \bbcccddd=undefined.
l.29 \show\bbcccddd
```

Comment: Hmmm.... Thank you. Wouldn't it be simpler to use `\ifundef` rather than spinning a custom test? Or will that not work?

Comment: @cfr Maybe `\ifundef` doesn't leave a command defined. But this is package free. ;-)

Comment: Sure. But packages are just code ;). Besides, I'm already using `etoolbox`. The only thing using `\ifundef` changes is that I need to load it a little earlier. Unless you also have code for `\AtEndPreamble{...}`? ;) Frankly my code is such a mess, that loading a few dozen packages is really neither here nor there.